# Why listeners don't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I wan't to remove message item on 'Delete' button.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W0lfdalE/GTbT3/)

```
$('.message-delete').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html is appended dynamically after DOM load use [delegated event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click','.message-delete', function () {
    ...........
});
```

See [**event delegation HERE**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)